# Value not displayed into Spring MVC view

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp, jstl

I'm having a problem with displaying a string in jsp view. A a web framework I'm using Spring MVC.

The view (return.jsp) is like that:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>FredomWings</title>
</head>

<body>
<b>Result -></b>
<p>${currentValue}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The controller looks like that:

```
     @RequestMapping(value="balance")
        public String getBalance(Model model) {



            model.addAttribute("currentValue","alalal");

            return "return";
}
```

What is the reason for which in the jsp page only Result -> without any value is displayed?

Comment: add these line at top `<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@page isELIgnored="false" %>` of your jsp page.

Comment: it dosen't work; anyway they are already included

Comment: Show me the output/error of your this code?

Comment: did you get "${currentValue}" as an output?